# How can I see the systemd-resolve DNS cache?

Tags: dns, cache, systemd-resolved

Using `sudo systemd-resolve --statistics` I can see the current DNS cache statistics, for example:

```
Cache                     
  Current Cache Size: 68  
          Cache Hits: 412 
        Cache Misses: 461
```

I would like to see all the entries of the DNS cache (here 68), is it possible?

Comment: think you can do: *killall -USR1 systemd-resolved* (the output will be redirected to journald)

Comment: But this is going to kill the process rather than printing the cache?

Comment: no, it wil just sending SIGUSR1 to systemd-resolved, you can find a description in *man systemd-resolved*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the following command to send signal `USR1` (User-defined signal 1) to `systemd-resolved`:

```
sudo pkill -USR1 systemd-resolve
```

This will NOT stop the service. It just [tells `systemd-resolved` to write all the current cache entries](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html) (and some other information) to the system log.

You can then export the log messages written by `systemd-resolved` to a text file with the following command:

```
sudo journalctl -u systemd-resolved > ~/resolved.txt
```

Open the text file generated this way in the text editor of your choice and search for `CACHE:`. After this, the list of cache entries will follow.

Please note that the text file might contain several lines containing `CACHE:`.